# Facebook 3.0 Sdk open authorized app dialog on every request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

In Facebook 2.5 graph API whenever you post a publish request you just have to call the request method like this -

```
Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/photos", parameters,"POST"));
```

Facebook will automatically publish the photo (or text) if you are already authorized.

But in new graph API 3.0 every time I send a request, Facebook opens the authorize dialog. I am able to publish photos and videos but I don't want to open the dialog if the session is already open after authorization. This is my code -

```
private void uploadVideo() {
        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        final Request request;

        if(session.isOpened())
        {

            OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(getActivity());
            openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            openRequest.setCallback(null);

            List<String> PERMISSIONS = new ArrayList<String>();
            PERMISSIONS.add("publish_stream");


            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

            Callback callback = new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            };

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/123.mp4");
            if(file.exists())
            {
                try {
                    request = Request.newUploadVideoRequest(session, file, callback);
                    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                    task.execute();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

### UPDATE

I tried replacing these two lines -

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS);
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

with this-

```
openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
```

By doing this its not showing authorization dialog but the success is rate 2 out 3. Sometimes the response message state -

> Unexpected error occurs.

Comment: it seems to me that setting the `SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO` will force the dialog every time

Comment: read updated question.

Comment: what type of erro, please give all the information possible